# jQuery Simple "Search/Filter" System

Tags: php, jquery

I'm coding a website for my personal usage and for training.
In this one, I'm trying to code a folder system, which works perfectly. I'm pretty proud of it.

Anyway I'm trying to a filter search in jQuery. This hides all folders which do not match with the input value. But the trouble is that the user need to write in the input the EXACTLY same name as the folder.

My code is the following:

```
while($data = $ans->fetch()) {
  echo'<div class="col-md-3" id="'.$data['name'].'"><div class="jumbotron">
  <img src="../img/folder.png" height="15%">
  <p>'.$data['name'].'</p>
  <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="?parent='.$data['id'].'" role="button">Aller</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="btn btn-danger btn-lg " href="?delete='.$data['id'].'" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></p>
</div></div>';
}
```

This echos a Div for each folder in the DB. And the JQ is the following:

```
$("#search").keyup(function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        if(value == ''){
            $('.col-md-3').show(100);
        }
        else{
            $('.col-md-3').hide(100);
            $('#'+value).show(100);

        }
    });
```

I've just create the system myself without looking at any tutorials, it's why the thing is not optimized.
If someone knows how to not hide by example a folder named: StackOverflow

When I'm Typing: Stack !

Comment: Not to be that guy, but I just had to: https://www.grammarly.com/blog/how-to-use-an-exclamation-point-properly-how-not-to-use-it/

Answer (score 1):

Use Regular expression:

```
(new RegExp('word')).test(str)
```

or

```
str.indexOf(inputString); //it returns =-1 if contains or returns >-1
```